# Autocomplete empty if don't select

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I need to know how to clear the textbox if the user type only 1 character and don't select on the list? I also have a ajax in autocomplete.php which I need to get the value send to textbox.

This what I have right now.

```
</script>
function changeAutoComplete (val) {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        mustMatch: true,
        source: 'autocomplete.php?selected='+val,
        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
                $(this).val("");
                return false;
                $("#empty-message").css({display:'', overflow: 'hidden'});
            } else {
                $("#empty-message").empty();
                $("#empty-message").css({display:'none', overflow: 'hidden'});
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>

 Drop1
 <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category GROUP BY cat_code ORDER BY id");
    $option = '';
     while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['cat_code'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>

<select id="main" name="main" onchange="changeAutoComplete(this.value)">
<option value=""  selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>

<div class="demo-frame">
Tags
<input id="tags" name="items">
<div id="empty-message" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

**autocomplete.php**

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015") or die("Database Error");
    $auto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["term"]);
    $selected = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["selected"]);

    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' AND cat_code='$selected' GROUP BY id ORDER BY item" ); 

    if($sql)
    {
        $str = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $str[] = $row['item'];
        }
        echo json_encode($str);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you post all the code i.e. the textbox etc

Comment: check this link this might help you http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-close

Comment: @SohilDesai I think `close` event is not the place for here.  What happens `if a character entered` is not in the list at all? then the close event will not be triggered.

Comment: @SohilDesai Here check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/689Uf/2/) here try with `z` and then you will understand what I tried to say

Comment: @Praveen: thanks I got your point. Now, I think you are looking for autocomplete for combobox. check this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case it better to do this with **`blur`** event.  Here go with this

```
$('#tags').on('blur', function () {
    if ($(this).val().length === 1) {  //check for no. of characters entered
        $(this).val('');  // clear the textbox
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/689Uf/1/)

### Updates:

As from your comments, it would be better to go with **`change`** event,

```
 change: function (event, ui) {
              if (!ui.item) {
                  $(this).val("");
                  $('#empty-message').show();
              } else {
                  $('#empty-message').hide();
              }
          }
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/689Uf/4/)

Comment: that right, but the problem with that is when I input 2 or more letters it doesn't clear the textbox

Comment: it's possible to mix it up inside of response: function(event, ui) ?

Comment: @user3318208 I don't understand `I input 2 or more letters it doesn't clear the textbox`. can you elaborate?

Comment: what I mean i.e on the list is ballpen and pencil. If I input pe and don't select on pencil the textbox is not clear.

Comment: @user3318208 oh I got it.  It is like forcing a user to select from the list.  Then you can simply do this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/689Uf/3/)

Comment: It almost a week that I can't rid of this. But all I need is just change: function (event, ui) :/ it works.

Comment: Just a little concern, I need the message if the value is not on list

Comment: @user3318208 that is a simple one my friend, you should have tried it yourself.  anyway check it http://jsfiddle.net/689Uf/4/

Comment: This works fine, but it causes another issue...i.e. if you enter same search term again, it doesn't show the suggestions. You should use `$(this).data().autocomplete.term = null;` to clear search term as well.